# Check if any property in class has been set

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do a simple check - I want the ability to check any object, and to see if at least one of its properties have been set (not equal to null). At the moment I can achieve this using reflection to get all fields and check each one by one, but this is very slow. Is there another way of doing this?

The only (sort of hacky) way of doing it I could think of is to create a new Object, where all properties should be initialised to null, and check if the other object equals it

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would say that the reflection method is 'hacky' while the new object and compare method is the normal one.

Comment: You don't have to write `Java` in the title if it's tagged.

Comment: Could you provide the way you're doing it using reflection?

Comment: You can use constructor with parameters or factory to ensure consistency of your objects. Doing this way you'll not need to check it later

Comment: Could you just write a method in the Object class, like isSet, that returns a boolean true if one of the properties in the class has been set?

Comment: To create a new instance the class will need no arg constructor (unless you come other with some sort of parameter defaulting mechanism) and using the `equals` method makes the assumption that each class overrides `equals` and that the overridden implementation performs a comparison of every field - neither of which is guaranteed.  What is it you're trying to achieve by testing fields for initialization?

Comment: For the object in question, I just need to make sure that at least one of the properties (which are objects themselves) is not set to null

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to check the properties - I ask because there may be a better way to achieve that goal.

Comment: @SCassidy1986, I agree with Nick Holt and want to ask you another question - why don't you want to make your objects always be in usable state? Maybe you can prohibit creation of object with all fields set to null, so all the checks for validity will be in constructors or factories?

Comment: I can't really explain too much as it's for work - the object I need to check will contain roughly 10 objects (or more, if added later) and at least one needs to be set, so using annotations and a validator I was hoping for a way to check this without resorting to a massive if-then-else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want this check to work generically on absolutely *any* object - **whether you own it or not** - I think using reflection is the only way to achieve this.

Indeed, this kind of meta-programming check is exactly the type of thing reflection is for.

Using a comparison with a new object instance will only work when you can guarantee that all the object's (non primitive) instance variables will be `null` immediately following construction (**update** - and that `.equals()` is overridden to compare every field) which you can't in the general case.

e.g. the class you want to run the check on may define a no-arg constructor which initialises some of the instance variables, or some instance variables may be initialised inline at declaration.

Comment: Eventually went with the reflection route - sadly the comparing to a "null" object didn't work without implementing the .equals(Object) method, which would involve having to compare each property which is what I was hoping to avoid!

Comment: Yeah that's a good point as well, you'd obviously also have to assume the equals method was comparing every field so you'd need control over that implementation too - answer updated

Answer (score 6):

You could write an interface `NullCheckable`

```
public interface NullCheckable {
    boolean areAllPropertiesNull();
}
```

Then each class you want to be able to check implements this interface with the appropriate method e.g.

```
public class Class1 implements NullCheckable {

    private Object property1;

    public Object getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllPropertiesNull() {
        return property1 == null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have an interface INullCheckableWrapper with a INullCheckable property and the check will be inside the property get?

Answer (score 2):

An improvement to Joe Elleson's method may be to provide an abstract class

```
public abstract class NullChecker{

  protected abstract Object[] getPropertiesToCheck();

  protected boolean checkForNonNull(){
    Object[] props=getPropertiesToCheck();
    for(Object obj:props){
       if(obj!=null){
           return true;
       }
    }
  }
```

and then extend it and provide the properties in a the method implementation in each class like

```
public Object[] getPropertiesToCheck(){
   return new Object[]{property1,property2,property3};
}
```